# Cant receive value from reg expression extractor at Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I created a test plan with two requests. In the first request I receive a JSON response from which I select an auth token. In the second request I should reach a page with this token, but instead I get: `Authorization: Bearer ${token}''`

First response:

```
{"message":"Success","authentication_token":"UG5FzqsXNb9jnvG8dzbo","token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"","user_id":1,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}
```

Regular expression:

```
"authentication_token":"(.+?)"
```

The regular expression seems to be OK. I tested it with the View Results Tree. I still have `Authorization: Bearer ${token}''` in the second request.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse JSON.

Comment: How i can get value from response in other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562060/jmeter-extracting-fields-in-json-response

Comment: Don't know jmeter or json. Assume I know regex, can you give a clear usage example and explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to parse json - is to use JMeter Plugin [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/).
Find good example [here](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) ('Parsing JSON' subtitle)

Anyway, RexExp and Xpath Extractor should work. How do you use it? Could you provide more details?