# How the JSON value extract process in jmeter response data using regular expression extractor

Tags: json, web-services, automation, jmeter

```
{  
  "response":{  
    "statusCode":"00",
    "status":"success",
            "responseData":
             [
                   {  
                     "status":1,
                     "themeID":27,
                     "themeName":"ThemeName25",
                     "templateId":22
                    }
             },
                  {  
                     "status":1,
                     "themeID":28,
                     "themeName":"ThemeName28",
                     "templateId":28
                  }
             }
             ]
}
```

Here need to extract the json values from first and second array But without the use of jmeter plugins like JSON PATH EXTRACTOR. Can anyone suggest the idea for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter extracting fields/parsing JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562060/jmeter-extracting-fields-parsing-json-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is usually much faster compared to other extractors like XPath, JSON etc - Check [this site](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/) for the comparison.

Lets assume we are trying to get the value of all the theme ids from the JSON.
Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and update the details as shown here.

[image]

1. You need a reference name to store the value found
2. The pattern to check
3. Template used to create a string from the matches found
4. -1 for all matches, 0 for random, 1 for first ..etc

[image]

1. `<variable>_matchNr` will give the total matches
2. `theme.id_1` will return the first match which is `27`
3. `theme.id_2` will return the second match which is `28`

More details and examples are [here](https://blog.flood.io/guide-to-jmeter-regular-expressions/).