# how to format JSON response in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can I format json response in jmeter?
I don't want to tell which part of json answer
should be showed. I want to see my response not as
very long one line but as many lines formatted with new lines and
tabs/spaces.

I saw:

- http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/
- [Jmeter extracting fields/parsing JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562060/jmeter-extracting-fields-parsing-json-response)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [JSON Formatter PostProcessor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONFormatter/) is what you're looking for

[image: JSON Formatter PostProcessor]

If it is not suitable for you - take a look at [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance), it provides `prev` pre-defined variable (basically [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) instance) which gives read/write access to the parent sampler(s) response data so you will be able to do anything you want with the response using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language